# Changing all comments' size in range to autosize

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that turns all comments size to autosize, however as I have quite a few cells with comments, this code runs a little slow, to the point where it will become non responsive for awhile.

```
Sub AutoSizeComments()
    Dim c as range, ws as worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'Loop through each comment on worksheet
    For Each c In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)

        c.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

    Next c
End Sub
```

After some research online, I still could not find a way to make this faster. As I am new to VBA coding, I am not sure if there is any way to make this code run faster. Thanks for helping and if this is the fastest way, let me know too. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I research more and tried different ways, I have found that I can use the application.screenupdating way to make my whole program run faster and since this question have been unanswered for quite awhile, I will mark this as my answer once a week has past since I asked this question. however I will still be checking to see if there is any better answers posted here till then. Thank you all!

```
Sub AutoSizeComments()
    Dim c as range, ws as worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Loop through each comment on worksheet
    For Each c In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
        c.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```